# Read XLS file in memory ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an xls file sitting in a byte[] as a result of a file upload on my asp.net web application. Is there a library that can read in and process the xls file as a byte[]? I do not want to save the file to disk.

All I need to do is be able to read the cell contents (I would prefer to accept csv file if I had the choice).

I discovered SpreadsheetGear which claims to do this, but I would rather not pay $1000 for software that does way more than I need it to.

Note that I am referring to XLS file and not XLSX file, but I would appreciate advice on both.

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/). And if you are dealing with OpenXML (`.xlsx`) you may checkout the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124).

Answer (score 1):

EPPlus is also a solid library for working with Excel files. It has some samples that will show how to interact with a file from a MemoryStream.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

NOPI has a really good library and it picks up where EPPlus leaves off.  http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to XLS suggests the older Excel 97 format, which in that case you can use the ExcelWorkbook / ExcelWorksheet reader code provided as part of the Tarantino project at the [Tarantino Bitbucket Repository](https://bitbucket.org/headspringlabs/tarantino/src/92c38430616f/src/Tarantino.Core/Commons/Services/DataFileManagement/Impl/)

You can pass your XLS in memory as a stream and the helper methods will return a DataSet with workbook data and Tables representing Sheets. You do not need the entire Tarantino project code and can simply grab:

- ExcelWorkbookReader.cs
- ExcelWorksheetReader.cs
- IExcelWorkbookReader.cs
- IExcelWorksheetReader.cs

and add these files to your solution.

Using the interface is simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploadfile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var reader = new ExcelWorkbookReader();
    var data = reader.GetWorkbookData(file.InputStream);

    // Do something with the data here

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read a .xls content without Excel library using ADO.NET and OLEDB driver. But the worksheet must be in "table" format. If this is true, its works fine.

The connection string should be something like this:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";

Regards.